# android - platform incompatible and package incompatible error when installing application on phone

Tags: android, build, platform, android-2.2-froyo

i have made an android application for 
"Project Build Target" as

Target name:: "Android 2.2"

Vendor :: "Android Open Source Project"

Platform :: "2.2"

API Level :: "8"

I am using Eclipse helios and android sdk r_06.

But the phone where i am want to run my application has platform 1.6

how do make this application run on that phone with that platform because when i installed the application it gave me error "incompatible platform","package corrupted","package not found"

how do i make it compatible??

also in eclipse when i changed target name as "Android 1.5" it gave me error in res folder tellin "invalid resources directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install an older version of the SDK there are instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html). Make sure you get one for 1.6 or less. You may or may not need to change your code to make it run on the earlier version.

Comment: i am not getting any error when i run this on my emulator..
but will it give any error on phone??
as i just changed target name to 1.6 and minSdkVersion to 4